# [Bash-Python]: reading the bash variable passed to python

Tags: python, bash

i have a script python which take as input a variable generated in bash:

`source <(python3 ${bin_path}/jd_to_date.py ${data[0]0:5})`

where data is a an array composed by a lot of value like these: 57235003472222219e+04.....and ${data[0]0:5} should be 57235

in python i use this code for reading the variable:

```
mjd = sys.argv[1]
```

but when i execute the bash program i obtain this output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/project/demetra/bin/jd_to_date.py", line 47, in <module>
jd_to_mjd()
File "/opt/project/demetra/bin/jd_to_date.py", line 8, in jd_to_mjd
jd_n=int(mjd)+2400000.5
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '003472222219e+04'
```

it seems that the read variable is the second part of the data value. How it is possible?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

`data[0]=57235003472222219e+04; echo ${data[0]0:5}`
as noted prints "003472222219e+04"

I'm pretty sure you want:

`data[0]=57235003472222219e+04; echo ${data[0]:0:5}`
which prints out the desired "57235"

(where the key change is the : between the closing square bracket and the zero)

Comment: :D sorry, are too many hours i am on the screen. I will take a cofee...thank you